# Where are the building entrances in Zombies?

Tags: zombies

It has never been clear where the entrances in to and out of buildings are from roads. Some are obvious when there is only a single road segment:

[image: Police Station Zombies!!! board]

Others are multi-square builds along side a multi-square road (e.g. the gas station). Some like the army surplus store has an obvious door way:

[image: Army Surplus Zombies!!! board]

But others are less obvious, like the hardware store with fenced parking lots, the toy store with non-obvious doorways, etc. Which road segments can the building be entered from? I could not find details on this in the rules or the Zombies FAQ.

I feel like the density of the bright white border lines contains a clue, but nothing seemed to make sense there either. For example, the starting tile (above) has bright lines between the road segments.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this question despite the fact that I traded my *Zombies!!!* stuff in on other games some time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only available answer may be: that there is no certain answer, but the building entrances should be located by player agreement, based on the application of some degree of common sense to the visual appearance of the tiles.

I don't own Zombies, but I remember when I played it I thought it was definitely a "fast and loose" style of game design, rather than having the sort of very precise, loophole-closing ruleset that I personally prefer.  Bad news for us obsessive-compulsive rules lawyers, in other words!

Comment: I guess I'm gonna have to get a marker and create some house rules for entrances.